# Instagram feed with Zend framework 2

Tags: php, curl, zend-framework2, feed, instagram

I'm trying to use a simple code to get my Instagram feed. I'm using Zend framework 2 with zend server (as a localhost).

I'm using the code given [here](http://bradsknutson.com/blog/using-instagrams-api-create-image-gallery).

I activated curl in my `php.ini` so I guess the problem would not come from here.

I just copied the code in my `layout.php`, in the footer part.

Here what it is saying :

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /usr/local/zend/apache2/htdocs/zend/module/Application/view/layout/layout.phtml on line 114

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/local/zend/apache2/htdocs/zend/module/Application/view/layout/layout.phtml on line 114

Line 114 :

foreach ($result->data as $post){
```

See below the screenshot of the informations given by Zend server:

[image: screenshot]

and here the info given by var_dump($result) before the json_decode()

[image: var_dump]

Comment: Your code is expecting `$result->data` to contain an array of data but it does not. You need to debug this a little - try `var_dump($result)` to see what it does contain. This might give you some clues as to what's wrong.

Comment: Presumably you meant you're using this code -> http://bradsknutson.com/blog/using-instagrams-api-create-image-gallery/#comment-84474 Do what @TimFountain says, but be sure to dump the `$result` **before** the `json_decode()` call, at a guess it's not a json string. By the way, this has nothing to do with zf2.

Comment: Okay good to know it is not related with zf2, i was scared that i could not use it inside my zf2 application.

var_dump($result) is giving NULL

Comment: Sorry i was dumping after the json_decode(). It is saying page not found. So am i guessing right if i say it could come from the access token or user id? I generated it from my localhost address (http://zend.mac).

I edited the main post so you can see the screenshot of the var_dump($result)

Comment: In that case, check the URL you're connecting to, as that's where the issue lies. Try loading it up in a web browser.

Comment: Okay I did again step by step the generation of the access token. I might have be wrong in one of the step so my access token was probably wrong. Everything are working now. Thank you for your time !